# Mod Rewrite question

Tags: mod-rewrite

How can I have Example 1 and Example 2 both point to Example 3 using mod rewrite. so far I can point to Example 2.

Example 1

```
http://www.example.com/posts/1/abcd/
```

Example 2

```
http://www.example.com/posts/1/abcd
```

Example 3

```
http://www.example.com/posts.php?aid=1
```

Here is my mode rewrite

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^posts/([^/]*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /posts.php?aid=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add (/?) at the end of the regular expression to say that there can be one or no / char AND you have to remove the beginning ^ char what stands for the beginning of a line:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /posts/([^/]*)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(/?)$ /posts.php?aid=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: why do I have to remove the ^ char?

Comment: The ^ char says that the expression "posts" has to be the first expression of the url, like "posts/1/abcd". The full URL expression fails because it starts with "http" and not "posts".